# Import libGDX as just 3d engine

Tags: android, c++, 3d, libgdx, java-native-interface

I have written an app which loads, saves and displays 3d models. They won't have sophisticated Textures but propably extreme meshes (+200MB). The engine i am currently using (jpct-ae) runs completely in java which is slow and very limited on RAM.

So can anyone tell me or point me to information, how to use libGDX as JUST a 3d engine (render, transformations...) and not as full blown gameframework. I want to render to only one view on an layout. Does libGDX store its mesh data to c++/jni RAM or to JVM?

Comment: Your question asks about libGDX but I think there is a more basic one regarding performance? for your models. Have you checked/used the performance tools to see what your problem is as I'm not sure how the JNI layer will help you if you are going to hit the OpenGL ES limits. 200MB sounds large but is that an obj model text file size vs true number of vertices.

Comment: Yes and no. I won't have any influence on the models, the client will be loading (binary .STL file with 200MB is just one of his files). Memory allocated in C++ code won't suffer from the heap limits on the Android JVM. Thats why i would love to store the whole render and geometry in C++. However my experience with c++ is still terribly limited.

Comment: Sorry don't know the how libGDX does mesh data, I assume you've seen or are trying to accomplish something similar to this: http://www.kiwiviewer.org/. I haven't done anything with it but it appears to be open-source, it may be worth investigation.

Comment: I haven't seen this project yet. But since it uses CMake it does for sure run with c++. My java implementation needs an Kepler core cpu/gpu to run this FPS. Thanks for that, i will try to alternate kiwiviewer to implement my own engine.